# Find frequency and amplitude of a signal [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

my signal is a vector like this:

[image]

I want to find the frequency and amplitude of this signal. Any idea how can I do it using Matlab?

FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) is giving this result:

[image]

Remark: In this case I can find the peaks and extract the frequency according to the time, which is ~13Hz. But can't find the magnitude. In general I have more signals from which the frequency estimation is not as obvious as here.

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can provide the code to generate the signal? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: if you want to remove the DC drift in your angular movement, try substracting the mean of the angular velocity before you integrate it.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 The signal comes from a sensor, sampling at 500Hz. It is a gyro, which gives the angular velocity. By integrating it I have the angular movement (rotation). But because of the integration the result drifts over time (that's why it is not horizontal). What I need is to find the frequency and amplitude of the rotation movement.